# Using RODBC with long SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I have a long SQL query that generates a n*5 matrix when executed. I would like to loop through this 5 times, changing the year from 2008 to 2013. This will produce 5 matrices, all with 5 columns but each with a different number of rows. I would like to append each matrix onto each other into one big matrix. I already know that the total number of rows in the big matrix should be 17526.

The current code is like this:

```
library(RODBC)
conn = odbcConnect(dsn = "database name")

startyear=2008
endyear=2013  
results=data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 17526))

for (i in startyear:endyear) {
query = paste("
SQL CODE
")
results[i] = sqlQuery(conn, query) }
```

2 Questions:

1. Is there a way to have the paste command not print in the console? The SQL query is over 600 lines and takes a while to print.
2. Any guesses as to why the loop doesn't work, as constructed? If I do not loop but rather set i equal to some year it works.

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more information about your code, because based on your description something else has to be happening inside the paste() part that you haven't included.

Comment: If I make startyear and endyear the same, and change the results data frame to match the appropriate number of rows, I get this error message: new columns would leave holes after existing columns. If I take it out of the loop entirely, and set i=2013, it works.

Comment: Look, that's not even close to enough information. All I can tell you is that I have no idea what you're intending with `results[i] = ...`. Are you trying to append the result as a new column? Because that would require `result[[i]] = ...`. But it's unlikely that you have a data frame with 2008 columns, and that could be the source of your error.

Comment: I am trying to append the result as new rows. So matrix after one iteration through the loop is say 3000 rows. Then I want to append the second iteration at the end of that, and continue on. So the end product being one giant matrix with 5 columns, which were the result of smaller matrices, each having the same 5 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `rbind`, `do.call` and `lapply`:

```
  ret <- lapply(startyear:endyear, function(i) {
                  query = paste("
                            SQL CODE
                          ")
                  sqlQuery(conn, query)
                })
  final <- do.call(rbind, ret)
```

Or better yet:

```
final <- do.call(rbind(lapply(
            startyear:endyear, function(i)
                sqlQuery(conn, paste("
                                SQL CODE
                               "))
              )))
```

Comment: glad it worked for you.   I fixed the typo in the second part